# Fifa 13 Progression to FA cup Semi final

Tags: fifa-13

I know Fifa 13 is a bit behind the times but I think I found a glitch or something  during gameplay.
I am on my 2nd season as manager of Liverpool and progressed through a tense quarter-final which finished with me winning 3-1 at spurs (4-2) on aggregate. First Game at Anfield was a draw.Although this seemed to be the case during my fixture check I noticed it was Spurs that progressed to the Semi-Finals and not me. Can anyone offer me a workaround around this annoying problem?

Comment: 3-1 away means the Spurs won their home game and yours ended up 1-1..? Can you provide a screenshot of the results?

Comment: User dly as requested I have added some information clarifying the result. Hope that helps.